# Using end= parameter in loop (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

My desired output is two half pyramids separated by two spaces.

```
length = int(input("Enter size of pyramid."))
hashes = 2
for i in range(0, length):
    spaces = length - (i+1)
    hashes = 2+i
    print("", end=" "*spaces)
    print("#", end=" "*hashes)
    print("  ", end="")
    print("#" * hashes)
```

However, this ends up printing only the first hashes of each row on the left pyramid. If I get rid of the `end=` in line 7, the pyramids are both printed correctly, but with newlines after each row. Here are the outputs:

With end=:

```
   #    ##
  #     ###
 #      ####
#       #####
```

Without end=:

```
   ##
  ##
  ###
  ###
 ####
  ####
#####
  #####
```

All I want now is to have the second output, but without the newlines.

Comment: What do you mean without the new lines?

Comment: @DanielMesejo without the newlines in between each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to print any output you want without newlines is to uses `sys.stdout.write`. This writes a string to the `stdout` without appending a new line.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("foo")
foo>>> sys.stdout.flush()
>>>
```

As you can see above, `"foo"` is written with no newline.

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying the `end` parameter by the number of hashes, instead of multiplying the main text portion.

Try this modification:

```
length = int(input("Enter size of pyramid."))
hashes = 2
for i in range(0, length):
    spaces = length - (i+1)
    hashes = 2+i
    print(" " * spaces, end="")
    print("#" * hashes, end="")
    print("  ", end="")
    print("#" * hashes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this algorithm:

```
length = int(input("Enter size of pyramid."))
# Build left side, then rotate and print all in one line
for i in range(0, length):
    spaces = [" "] * (length - i - 1)
    hashes = ["#"] * (1 + i)
    builder = spaces + hashes + [" "]
    line = ''.join(builder) + ''.join(builder[::-1])
    print(line)
```